# Android WifiInfo.getIpAddress returns 0 Android on Nexus 5X with Android 6

Tags: java, android, networking, ip, wifi

Here is what I am doing:

I register a BroadcastReceiver like this:

```
mConnectionChangeReceiver = new ConnectionChangeReceiver();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
filter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
filter.addAction(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
mContext.registerReceiver(mConnectionChangeReceiver, filter, null, handler);
```

Then I automatically try connect to a specific WiFi. Something like this:

```
if (!mWifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
    mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
}
mWifiManager.enableNetwork(mCurrentNetworkId, true);
```

I get the broadcast receiver events as expected. Inside `onReceive()` I check for the SSID and for `SuplicantState`. The problem is when I try to get the phone ip address. `WifiInfo.getIpAddress` returns 0 if the cellular network is enabled on the phone but it works if it is disabled.

Please note that this will work if the device was already connected to SSID in both cases (with/without cellular network). For this to happen wifi must de off or the phone must be connected to another wifi before running the code.

Here's the code:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {        
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = mWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

    //..... Here's the code that compares SSID

    if (isConnectedToSSID() && (wifiInfo.getSupplicantState() == SupplicantState.COMPLETED) {    
        mIpAddress = NetworkHelper.getIpAddress(wifiInfo);   
    }
}

public static String getIpAddress(WifiInfo pWifiInfo) {
    int ipAddress = pWifiInfo.getIpAddress();
    if (ByteOrder.nativeOrder().equals(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)) {
        ipAddress = Integer.reverseBytes(ipAddress);
    }

    byte[] ipByteArray = BigInteger.valueOf(ipAddress).toByteArray();
    String ipAddressString = null;
    try {
        ipAddressString = InetAddress.getByAddress(ipByteArray).getHostAddress();
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ipAddressString;
}
```

Any ideas why this happens?